# Uploading Image using Ajax, jQuery and Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to add a feature where I can attach an image in the form using Codeigniter, Ajax, jQuery. The form submits and when I check the database for the image file, it seems that it doesnt have anything on it. Usually they use FormData but, I already started using this method. I was wondering if there is anyway I could do it this way.

Here are my codes.

jQuery

```
$('#addForm').submit(function(event){ 
        var emp_id = $("#agentNames").val();
        var campaign = $("#addCampaign").val();
        var k_type = $("#addKudosType").val();
        var c_name = $("#addCustomerName").val();
        var p_number = $("#addPhoneNumber").val();
        var e_add = $("#addEmailAdd").val();
        var comment = $("#addCustomerComment").val();
        var supervisor = $("#addSupervisor").val();
        var file = $("#addFile").val();
        var p_reward = $("#addPrefReward").val();
        var pfrd = $("#addProofreading").val();
        var k_card = $("#addKudosCard").val();
        var r_status = $("#addRewardStatus").val();

        dataString = "emp_id="+emp_id+"&campaign="+campaign+"&k_type="+k_type+"&c_name="+c_name+"&p_number="+p_number+"&e_add="+e_add+"&comment="+comment+"&supervisor="+supervisor+"&file="+file+"&p_reward="+p_reward+"&pfrd="+pfrd+"&k_card="+k_card+"&r_status="+r_status;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Kudos/addKudos/",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                alert("Succesfully Added!");
                location.reload();
            }
        });   
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Controller

```
public function addKudos()
{
    $emp_id= $this->input->post('emp_id');
    $campaign= $this->input->post('campaign');
    $k_type= $this->input->post('k_type');
    $c_name= $this->input->post('c_name');
    $p_number= $this->input->post('p_number');
    $e_add= $this->input->post('e_add');
    $comment= $this->input->post('comment');
    $supervisor= $this->input->post('supervisor');
    $file= $this->input->post('file');

    $config['upload_path'] = "uploads/images/";
    $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|png";
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['addFile']['name'];

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->initialize($config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('addFile')){
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
    } else {
        $picture = '';
    }

    $p_reward= $this->input->post('p_reward');
    $pfrd= $this->input->post('pfrd');
    $k_card= $this->input->post('k_card');
    $r_status= $this->input->post('r_status');
    $this->KudosModel->add_kudos($emp_id,$campaign,$k_type,$c_name,$p_number,$e_add,$comment,$supervisor,$picture,$p_reward,$pfrd,$k_card,$r_status);
}
```

Model

```
function add_kudos($emp_id,$campaign,$k_type,$c_name,$p_number,$e_add,$comment,$supervisor,$picture,$p_reward,$pfrd,$k_card,$r_status)
{
  $emp_id1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($emp_id));
  $campaign1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($campaign));
  $k_type1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($k_type));
  $c_name1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($c_name));
  $p_number1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($p_number));
  $e_add1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($e_add));
  $comment1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($comment));
  $supervisor1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($supervisor));
  $file1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($picture));
  $p_reward1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($p_reward));
  $pfrd1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($pfrd));
  $k_card1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($k_card));
  $r_status1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($r_status));

  $query =  $this->db->query("insert into tbl_kudos(emp_id,acc_id,kudos_type,client_name,phone_number,client_email,comment,uid,file,reward_type,proofreading,kudos_card,reward_status,is_given) values('$emp_id1','$campaign1','$k_type1','$c_name1','$p_number1','$e_add1','$comment1','$supervisor1','$file1','$p_reward1','$pfrd1','$k_card1','$r_status1',now())");
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41786755/3898339) question hope you get some idea

Comment: To troubleshoot go to your network tab in your browser developer console and do a var_dump($_POST) in your controller. your dataString does seem to be written for GET though, not sure how this will play out.

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't have any file because you aren't submitting any. You didn't show any HTML but you must have something like:

```
<input type="file" id="addfile">
```

But in jquery, you are retrieving the file using:

```
var file = $("#addFile").val();
```

Which will return the file name or an empty string because you won't get file contents (or image) using  `val()`. You need to look for another method to upload form data with file contents using AJAX. Check this out: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)